# Standalone chrome applications

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Currently I am exploring the possibilities and features of Google Chrome apps. As I see to run chrome apps we need to distribute them through chrome App Store. Could we develop a application as a chrome app, which will not need to release to general public or for a limited audience?

Is there anyway that we could package it to native OS executable like .exe in windows or .app in MacOS. So for users who doesn't have chrome installed will also can without any issue. Or at least could we distribute without submitting it to the App Store.

Also I am wondering whether we can run another application through chrome apps? For example I am planing to develop a java application and start with the chrome app.

Answer (score 2):

You can distribute a Chrome App without using the Chrome Web Store, but you'll have to explain to users how to install it, and it's a little tricky: They have to open the Extensions window in Chrome and then drag the installation file to that window. Upon dropping it, there will be a dialog asking them if they want it installed. (They can't just double-click on a file or do anything else that's easy like that.)

Chrome Apps can't directly launch native apps, but they can communicate in various ways with native apps (or any apps) once those other apps are running.

(Some parts of your question are ungrammatical, so I can't be completely sure what you're asking, but the above is what I think you're asking.)

Comment: I was only answering for Chrome Apps. Dragging to the Extensions page still works.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome *Extensions* are only installable from the Web Store, but *Applications* can be privately hosted with some provisos: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting